# OAUTH2: authorization decision Page isnt coming after successful form login

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am writing a form based OAUTH authentication for Getting The Authorization Code.It was supposed to have a "authorization decision Page"  after the Resource Server asks the Resource Owner to authenticate itself and as for authorization to share data.

**Below are the server side configs**

Authorization Server

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
     @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("javainuse").secret("{noop}secret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("read").authorities("CLIENT");
    }
}
```

WebSecurity Configurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class EmployeeSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

            return super.authenticationManager();
        }

     @Autowired
     private BCryptPasswordEncoder  passwordEncoder;



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesList")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {
        authenticationMgr.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"))
            .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }


}
```

**Below are the client side configs**

Controller

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEmployeeInfo() {
        return new ModelAndView("getEmployees");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeInfo1() {
        return "showEmployees";
    }
}
```

getEmployees.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 style="color: red;">Add New Employee</h3>

    <div id="addEmployee">
        <form:form action="http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize"
            method="post" modelAttribute="emp">
            <p>
                <label>Enter Employee Id</label>
                 <input type="text" name="response_type" value="code" /> 
                 <input type="text" name="client_id" value="javainuse" />
                 <input type="text" name="redirect_uri" value="http://localhost:8090/showEmployees" />
                 <input type="text" name="scope" value="read" /> 
                 <input type="SUBMIT" value="Get Employee info" />
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After providing login details on login prompt

[image]

i provided the details, after it should have provided me prompt at http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize

[image]

it is giving me info on logs

```
INFO AuthorizationEndpoint : Handling OAuth2 error: error="invalid_request", error_description="At least one redirect_uri must be registered with the client."
```

any help is really appreciated, not sure where i'm doing wrong.
I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE.

Comment: according to new OAUTH2 specs, you need to define atleast one redirectURI on your own, so i did that, after that problem solved,

Comment: what exactly did you do?

Answer (score 1):

The redirect_uri value http://localhost:8090/showEmployees which is given in the input tag  is also needs to be mapped in Authorization Server configuration above, so

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("javainuse").secret("secret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
        .scopes("read").authorities("CLIENT").redirectUris("http://localhost:8090/showEmployees");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding redirect URL in ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer will work.

Comment: It would be better to add some example.